# how to send all users list to a view in asp.net core 3 from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

how to send all users list to a view in asp.net core 3 mvc from controller

```
  public IActionResult Users()
            {
                var alluser = _db.Users.ToList();
                return View(alluser);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a class ApplicationDbUser as an example and inherit from IdentityUser to inherit all the properites from the AspNetUsers as follow :

```
public class ApplicationDbUser : IdentityUser
    {


    }
```

then you should use a context as a db (_db in your question) to get the data from the database using EntityFramework as the following code :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationDbUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
}
```

now in your controller you can use the code as the following :

```
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationDbUser> _userManager;

    public ExampleController(UserManager<ApplicationDbUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
         _userManager = userManager;
         _roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var allUsers = _userManager.Users.ToList();
        return View(allUsers);
    }
```

You can use it by using @model in the Index view page

in the Index.cshtml you can do the following :

```
@model IEnumerable<ApplicationDbUser>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>my page example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <table>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.Email
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```